Monomorphism to $\{\emptyset.\top\}$ implies equivalence to a sentence
I remember from a discussion the statement:
In the context category (I think of some geometric theory, but I do not think the property of theory matters.)
If $\{\vec{x}. \varphi\}\overset{[\theta]}\to \{\emptyset.T\}$ is a monomorphism, then there exists a $\psi$ with no variables, such that there is an isomorphism $\{\vec{x}.\varphi\} \overset{[\alpha]}\to \{\emptyset.\psi\}$ such that $[\psi]\circ [\alpha] = [\theta]$, where $[\psi]:\{\emptyset.\psi\}\to \{\emptyset.T\}$.
As far as I remember, it should appear somewhere in Sketch of Elephant. But the book is huge so I cannot identify its precise position.
May I please ask for an expanded proof for this?

I write $x$ and $y$ for arbitrary variable contexts, possibly empty, possibly with more than one variable. Everything I write holds in the context category for any theory in any logic extending regular logic.
Any arrow $\{x.\varphi\}\overset{[\theta]}\to \{y.\psi\}$ has an image factorization $$\{x.\varphi\}\overset{e}\to \{y.\exists x (\varphi(x)\land y = \theta(x))\}\overset{m}\to \{y.\psi\},$$ where $e$ is $[\theta]$ with restricted codomain, $m$ is the inclusion, and $m\circ e = [\theta]$. As in any regular category, when the original arrow $[\theta]$ is monic, $e$ is an isomorphism, so $\{x.\varphi\}$ is isomorphic to an object in variable context $y$.
Applying this to the case when $y$ is empty and $\psi$ is $\top$, the clause $y = \theta(x)$ is vacuous (since $y$ is empty), so we obtain an isomorphism $\{x,\varphi\}\cong \{\emptyset.\exists x\varphi\}$.

Thank you very much! May I please ask what exactly is the mono to ${[],\top}$? According to the construction in the Elephant, 1.4.4 says "$[\theta]$ is a mono iff $\theta\land\theta[\vec{x'}/\vec{x}]\vdash \vec{x} = {x'}$ is provable in $\mathbb T$.
". At first I think the monomorphism ${\vec{x}.\phi}\to {[].\top}$ is the formula $\vec{x'},\vec{x}.\phi\land \vec{x'} = \vec{x}$, but then I realize I am only allowed to use variables in $\vec{x}$. If I take the arrow to be $\vec{x}.\phi$, then it is not clear to me I can prove $\phi\land\phi[\vec{x'}/\vec{x}]\vdash \vec{x} = \vec{x'}$.

@Y.X. Every object ${x.\varphi}$ has a unique arrow to the terminal object ${[].\top}$, namely $[\varphi]$. This arrow is mono iff $\varphi(x)\land \varphi(x')\vdash x = x'$ is provable in $T$. For most formulas $\varphi$, this will not be provable! That's ok: most objects do not admit monic arrows to ${[].\top}$.

Ah thanks! My stupid. Makes sense.

But then what is intuitively a mono to the terminal object? A common thing to imagine about mono to the terminal is the inclusions to the identity cover of a space, but in this context I do not see any obvious analogy. Can we say something more than just “a property satisfied by a unique tuple”? (is it even a correct description?)

@Y.X. Intuitively, it's a proof that $\varphi$ has at most one element.

Thank you! Then a mono does not tell much.
